# Can't generate invoice programmatically

Tags: orders, invoice, order-status

I'm a building a function that should retrieve all the payments made in the last hour, and update the order status from pending to processing.

The problem is that, for some reason some of the orders (pending) return `false` when I do this:

```
$orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$order = $orderModel->load($entityId);
//$order->canInvoice() --> false
```

Do you have any idea/ sugestion?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should debug the canInvoice function to see what the problem might be. There are various reaons. Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per invoice `generation  is depending` upon on  `canInvoice()` function of sales model:

```
// File: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
public function canInvoice()
{
    if ($this->canUnhold() || $this->isPaymentReview()) {
        return false;
    }
    $state = $this->getState();
    if ($this->isCanceled() || $state === self::STATE_COMPLETE || $state === self::STATE_CLOSED) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getActionFlag(self::ACTION_FLAG_INVOICE) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    foreach ($this->getAllItems() as $item) {
        if ($item->getQtyToInvoice()>0 && !$item->getLockedDoInvoice()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Explanation:

**Condition1:** `if ($this->canUnhold() || $this->isPaymentReview())`  means if Order state is 
unhold or order state is payment review (this->getState() === self::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW;)

**Condition2:** `if ($this->isCanceled() || $state === self::STATE_COMPLETE || $state === self::STATE_CLOSED) {`

```
If order state is closed or complete or cancel.
```

**Condition 3:** `if ($this->getActionFlag(self::ACTION_FLAG_INVOICE)`,If current action is invoice

**Condition4:**  `if ($item->getQtyToInvoice()>0 && !$item->getLockedDoInvoice()) {`
if order all item qty_to_invoice value `is less than 1 and all item locked_do_invoice is null (In Sales_flat_order_item table).`

Hope ,you will understand

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but, can you clarify the Condition 4 please